# Many attributes are missing in attributes in design in Intellij Idea for android app develop

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea, attributes

I use the design part to design the android application in Intellij Idea, but I cannot design because many features such as "textColor", "textSize", "backgroundColor" are missing in the attributes part. When I try to write to the XML file manually, the automatic code completion does not work and does not recognize the functions.
I did a lot of research but couldn't find anything on this topic. I would be glad if you help.
I tried creating new project, invalidating the cache but it didn't work.

[attributes-----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGD0v.png)
[I'm looking for the attributes but nothing comes up------](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7vkx.png)
[I'm trying the XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBrL0.png)

-----------------update-------------

When I add a property to the XML file, it starts to appear in the attributes panel, but if I do not add it, it does not appear in the panel.
I couldn't understand why.
For example, when I add these properties to the textView, the properties appear on the panel, but when I add a new textView in the same project, the properties are not visible on the panel again.
How can I make these properties available in the attributes panel by default in the project?

In picture 1, the property does not appear in the attributes panel. When I add it manually to the XML file in Picture 2, it starts to appear on the panel.
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkvTs.png)
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFTZC.png)

Comment: Please post your xml layout content which may have any clues about what is the problem here.

Comment: @LJreplica I updated the question, can you take a look again